# Output directory not set in JobConf

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce

I am mentioning below the driver code of a simple mapR program

```
   import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public class CsvParserDriver {
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
          if(args.length != 2)
          {
              System.out.println("usage: [input] [output]");
              System.exit(-1);
          }

          JobConf conf = new JobConf(CsvParserDriver.class);
          Job job = new Job(conf);
          conf.setJobName("CsvParserDriver");

          FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

          conf.setMapperClass(CsvParserMapper.class);
          conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
          conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

          conf.setReducerClass(CsvParserReducer.class);
          conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

          conf.set("splitNode","NUM_AE");

          JobClient.runJob(conf);
      }
  }
```

I am running my code using the below command

```
hadoop jar CsvParser.jar CsvParserDriver /user/sritamd/TestData /user/sritamd/output
```

(All the respective jars and directories in the above command are created)

I get the **error** as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set in JobConf.
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create HDFS input and output directories as it was specified in the apache-hadoop-tutorial.

If you want to use local directory `file:///user/sritamd/TestData` - add FS prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by old API and new API.

Here is my new Job API to do configuration.

Step1: import new API lib

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
```

Step2: do configuration by new API job.

```
val job = Job.getInstance(conf)
job.getConfiguration.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[Put]])
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Suppose i want to use a custom record writer to write to some other database(not mysql as record writer is already in hadoop) then what should be configuration to remove this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the input and output directory to **conf** instead of **job** Like:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
 Job job = new Job(configuration, "MyConfig");
```

then

```
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HDFS filesystem might not be created you need to first format a given directory and the that directory can be used as input and output of files for Hadoop

/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format

Use link :-http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

and follow each step

Answer (score 0):

if you are running hadoop on standard mode (without cluster) for testing the code you dont need to have fs prefix to the output path. You can initialize Job and set the paths. Following code should work(make sure you are either using Job ( from org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job) or JobConf from org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf)

```
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJobName("Job Name");
        job.setJarByClass(MapReduceJob.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0:1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but fixed it. I used `job.waitForCompletion(true)` which caused spark on hbase to crash when using `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...)`.A
you should not wait for your job since it is using the old Hadoop api instead of the new API

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure that your directory is not already exist. If it exist Delete it.
- Second run your code in Eclipse, if it run properly and gives `ArrayOutofBounds` warning.

Otherwise, check your library that you inserted make sure to insert all CLIENT Libraries OR check that your class is in a package.

If all the above conditions meet your job will execute.